# Variable refrenced before assignment Python

Tags: python, variables

I went through this a couple of times and couldnt fine anything wrong so its probably something over my head. I also apology for what is going to be an assault on your eyes, its my first year of programming and have probably made multiple etiquette errors.

```
print('Befor we begin, when you are given options, I ask you to type your input as show, failure to do so will break the program and you will lose all of your progress')
def test():
    print('it has worked!')
def stats():
    global attack
    global health
    global mashealth
    global agility
    if race in ('human','Human'):
        maxatk=4
        maxagi=4
        attack = lambda:random.randint(2,maxatk)
        maxhealth = 20
        health=20
        agility = random.randint(maxagi,10)


    elif race in ('Orc','orc'):
        attack = random.randint(3,maxATK)
        maxhealth = 25
        agility = random.radint(maxAGI,10)


def main():
    while True:
        print('What would you like to do')
        print('Rest   Shop   Fight')
        answer=input('-')
        if answer in ('Rest','rest'):
            health=maxhealth
            continue

def character():
    global race
    global name
    global gender
    print('What would you like the name of your character to be?')
    name=input('-')
    print()
    print('What race will your character be?')
    print('Human   Orc   Elf')
    while True:
        race = input('-')
        if race in ('human','Human','Orc','orc','Elf','elf'):
            break
        else:
            print('Not a valid response, try again')
            continue
    print()
    print('What gender is your character')
    gender=input('-')
    print()

def goblin():
    goblinatk=1
    goblinhealth=100
    while True:
        print('You have encountered a goblin, what will you do?')
        do=input('-')
        if do == 'attack':
            damage=attack()
            goblinhealth=goblinhealth-damage
            print('You did',damage,'damage to the goblin')
            print('The goblin has',goblinhealth,'hp')
        goblinatk=lambda:random.randint(3,10)
        health=health-goblinatk
        print('the goblin did',goblinatk,'to you')
        print('you have',health,'hp')
        if goblinhealth <0:
            print('The goblin has died')
            break
        if health <0:
            print('you have died')
            break






character()
stats()
goblin()
test()
```

The error is here

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "H:\16CoFrega\Code\Python\GAME.py", line 255, in <module>
    goblin()
  File "H:\16CoFrega\Code\Python\GAME.py", line 238, in goblin
    health=health-goblinatk
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'health' referenced before assignment
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify the `health` as a global variable, otherwise it would be considered as a local variable, since you assign to it inside the function. Example -

```
def goblin():
    global health
    goblinatk=1
    goblinhealth=100
```

Answer (score 2):

```
def goblin():
    ............
    health=health-goblinatk
    ............
```

Look at this function definition. Your function doesn't know what `health` is, so it won't allow you to subscript something from `health`.

So, somehow function has to recognize what is `health`. Two most common way:

- First way, Declare `health` as a global variable. Now `health` can be recognized globally. But this is not the best way, as dealing with global variables are hard and error-prone and you are already handling too many global variables. So, i won't recommend it. I would rather suggest you to replace all the global variables with method 2. To understand why I am telling this, [Read This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19158339/why-are-global-variables-evil)
- Second way, the recommended way, is to pass the `health` variable as the parameter of the function and at the end, return it from the function.

Like this:

```
def goblin(health):
    ............
    health=health-goblinatk
    ............
    return health
```

If you are already returning something, don't worry. With python, you can return more than one variable as a tuple.

return statement:

```
return a,b,c
```

calling statement:

```
a,b,c = func()
```

Hope this helps :)